# < and > not displayed in string?

Tags: php, php-7

This is my code:

```
$xml = "<ITEMSTOCK>";
```

When I var_dump this, the string is empty. Removing the < and > makes it work, but I need those in the string. Whats wrong?

Comment: How are you viewing them?

Comment: I tried exactly the same in a sandbox, and I do see the <>

Comment: No repro: https://3v4l.org/f6rXA

Comment: Replace with &lt;ITEMSOCK&gt;

Comment: @Martijn The OP states: '*When I var_dump this, the string is empty. [...]*' hence my no repro comment.

Answer (score 4):

Check your source (*something like right-mouseclick->view source*), it's there.

It's a bit like this: `<strong>Hello</strong>`, you dont see those tags on your HTML page either. If you just echo `<strong>`, you wont see that on your page. And your tag acts the same (because a browser doesnt check if the html tag exists), you will see it in the actual source.

If you want to see it like that, you could do `echo htmlentities($xml);` which will convert all `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which are the html equivalents.